# To export query results from MySQL to CSV using SQL in macOS 12.6

Tags: mysql, sql, macos, mysql-workbench

I am trying to export query results from MySQL to CSV using SQL by the following query.

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM Book 
    INTO OUTFILE '/Users/<MY_NAME>/Desktop/folder1/folder2/book.csv'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

After executing above SQL query I am getting a following error.

> Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

I tried by editing `.my.cnf` file to `secure_file_priv=''`, But still I am getting same error.

I ran the `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'secure_file_priv';` query. But, I am getting:

```
# Variable_name, Value
'secure_file_priv', 'NULL'
```

Comment: Did you at least restart the server after changing the settings?

Comment: Yes, I did restart server after changing in the file. Still I am getting a same error.

Comment: You can't change `secure_file_priv` in your own `.my.cnf`, it has to be changed in the `my.cnf` for the database server.

Comment: Can you please tell me path for my.cnf for macOS. I can't find that file.